# How to add and remove a FontStyle to selected cells of a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where certain cells contain 2 or 3 digit numbers to 3 decimal places, e.g., 47.231.
I need to be able to change the Font style of some of these cells to `FontStyle.Strikeout`, preferably with a keydown (not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) and clicking on a cell.

Later, with a button event, I will be adding the sum of the values of the Cells in a Row to the right-most.
The sum should not include the value of the cell(s) with the strike through.
I am not sure of how to begin, however one slightly related post used code to change all cells containing certain words. See the code below.

```
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In frmCheckOut_Room.DataGridView2.Rows
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = r.Cells(9)
If cell.Value = "Void" Then
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    cell.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
ElseIf cell.Value = "Active" Then
    cell.Style.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8)
    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
End If
Next
```

Comment: How will you sum the data from left to right and the result in rightmost or from top to bottom and the result in right and buttom most

Comment: for each something1 in something2 automatically set something1 in step ahead row beginning from row 0, this row can be draw with cell.RowIndex or r.Index, so you can strike out any cell in this row that you define using this row index

Comment: Why would you want to use a key with the mouse but not an actual modifier key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simpler solution that I finally got working is shown below. It requires one button and using the mouse to select a cell. The last line of code removes the blue highlight of the cell with focus.

```
Private Sub BtnStrike_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStrike.Click
    If DGV1.CurrentCell.Value <> Nothing And DGV1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Empty Then
        DGV1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
        DGV1.CurrentCell.Style.Font = New Font(DGV1.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout)
    Else DGV1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
        DGV1.CurrentCell.Style.Font = New Font(DGV1.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    End If
    DGV1.CurrentCell.Selected = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.
You can toggle the **`FontStyle.Strikeout`** of any of the cells that contain *raw* values (values not generated by a calculation) either by using the ALT + Left Mouse button or pressing a Key (here, **`Keys.S`** is handled).
These combinations could be stored as in a configuration file.

Note: if you don't want to use key modifiers, you have to set the DataGridView's [EditMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode) to **`DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnF2`** or **`DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically`**, otherwise, the KeyDown event is not raised and the current cell will always enter edit mode.
Since `EditProgrammatically` adds complexity (you need to handle a lot of cases, otherwise exceptions raise), I've set it to `EditOnF2` (so, you need to press `F2` to enter edit mode). If you instead opt for a Key modifier + a Key (e.g., <kbd>Control + K</kbd>), you can keep the default `EditMode`.

There's a method that evaluates the current Font style:

```
Private Function GetCellFont(cell As DataGridViewCell) As Font
    Return If(IsNothing(cell.Style.Font), cell.InheritedStyle.Font, cell.Style.Font)
End Function
```

since a Cell may not have it's own Font set. It could be inherited. In this case, the `[DataGridViewCell].Style.Font` is null (`nothing`).

Subscribe to the DataGridView events in the Form's constructor or otherwise before binding the DataSource:

```
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellFormatting, AddressOf dgv_CellFormatting
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellMouseDown, AddressOf dgv_CellMouseDown
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellValueChanged, AddressOf dgv_CellValueChanged
AddHandler DataGridView1.KeyDown, AddressOf dgv_KeyDown
```

In the sample code (I've added an animation so the setup is more clear), the first three Columns hold the decimal values, the last two present the Sum and the Average values of all the Row's Cells where the **`StrikeOut`** style is not set.
The Average column is there just to show the use of [decimal.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round), to determine the number of decimal places to consider.

When the Font style of a Cell is toggled or a value is changed, the corresponding calculated values (Columns 3 and 4) are updated.

A Value change caused by editing a Cell is handled by the [CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged) event, calling the Form's [Validate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validate) method, which causes the DataGridView to format the cells which have a `Dirty` status.

---

[image: DataGridView Font Toggle]

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    If (e.RowIndex < 0) OrElse (e.ColumnIndex < 3) Then Return
    Dim value As Decimal = CalculateValues(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, DirectCast(sender, DataGridView))
    e.Value = value
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex > 2 Then Return
    Validate()
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
    If (e.RowIndex < 0) OrElse ((e.ColumnIndex < 0) OrElse (e.ColumnIndex > 2)) Then Return
    If (ModifierKeys <> Keys.Alt) OrElse (e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left) Then Return
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    ToggleCellFontStyle(dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim currentCell As DataGridViewCell = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.S AndAlso currentCell IsNot Nothing Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If (currentCell.ColumnIndex < 0) OrElse (currentCell.ColumnIndex > 2) Then Return
        ToggleCellFontStyle(DataGridView1.CurrentCell)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CalculateValues(columnIndex As Integer, rowIndex As Integer, dgv As DataGridView) As Decimal
    Dim sum As Decimal = 0.0D
    Dim avg As Decimal = 0.0D
    Dim valuesCounted As Integer = 0

    For col As Integer = 0 To 2
        Dim fStyle = GetCellFont(dgv(col, rowIndex)).Style And FontStyle.Strikeout
        If fStyle <> FontStyle.Strikeout Then
            valuesCounted += 1
            Dim cellValue = dgv(col, rowIndex).Value
            sum += CDec(If(cellValue Is DBNull.Value, 0.00D, cellValue))
        End If
    Next
    avg = Decimal.Round(If(valuesCounted > 0, sum / valuesCounted, 0.00D), 3)
    Return If(columnIndex = 3, sum, avg)
End Function

Private Sub ToggleCellFontStyle(cell As DataGridViewCell)

    Dim cellFont As Font = GetCellFont(cell)
    Dim cellFontStyle As FontStyle = cellFont.Style
    Dim isStrikeOut = (cellFontStyle And FontStyle.Strikeout) = FontStyle.Strikeout

    cellFontStyle = If(isStrikeOut, cellFontStyle Xor FontStyle.Strikeout, cellFontStyle Or FontStyle.Strikeout)
    cell.Style.Font?.Dispose()
    cell.Style.Font = New Font(cellFont, cellFontStyle)
End Sub

Private Function GetCellFont(cell As DataGridViewCell) As Font
    Return If(IsNothing(cell.Style.Font), cell.InheritedStyle.Font, cell.Style.Font)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works fine, however I am not used to using the middle mouse button. I need to simplify putting it into edit mode. Even a button would be more strait forward.

Comment: As of now, you can toggle the `Strikeout` with either Middle Button or pressing the `S` key. As you can see, these conditions are set in the `CellMouseDown` and `KeyDown` events. You can specify whatever combination of mouse buttons and/or keyboard keys you prefer.

Comment: I am not sure but I think there is an error in the KeyDown code. I find that the s key has no effect on anything except to add an s to a number.

Comment: Did you read the first part of the description? You have to set the DGV's `EditMode` to `EditOnF2`, if you want to use a single Key to toggle the Font's style (as you can see in the animation, pressing a key instead of the mouse button does toggle the style). With this setting, you have to press `F2` to enter a Cell's edit mode.

Comment: I stand corrected, I had not set EditMode to EditOnF2. If I am not pushing my luck too far...how would I change the code to edit on pressing the S key and a left click on the mouse in the cell to edit.

Comment: You'll need to rephrase that, I don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: how can I change the code so that when I press the alt key and click the left mouse button on a cell it changes from whatever the default font style to strikeout style.

Comment: See the edit (the `CellMouseDown` and `KeyDown` events and the `ToggleCellFontStyle` method have been modified. Replace the old ones with these).

Comment: Thank you, works great. I restrict keyboard input to numeric, back, minus and decimal.   Private Sub DGV1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DGV1.EditingControlShowing
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf MyCol_KeyPress
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyCol_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Or e.KeyChar = Chr(45) Or e.KeyChar = Chr(46) Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub